# How to get classes on individual days on material ui DatePicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, material-ui, classname

I have a date picker component I'm importing from material ui's "Pickers" where I'm trying to get a class on the individual days of the week with the component:

```js
            <DatePicker
              className={classNames(classes.datePicker)}
              onClose={() => this.onCloseStart()}
              classes={{ root: classNames(classes.dateRoot) }}
              open={openStart}
              dialogContentClassName={classNames(classes.contentClass)}
              DialogProps={{
                PaperProps: { className: classNames('picker', 'ck-time') },
              }}
              label="Start date"
              value={startValue}
              format="DD/MM/YYYY"
              onChange={(value) => onStartDateChange(value)}
              disableOpenOnEnter
              showTodayButton
              shouldDisableDate={disableStartDate}
              animateYearScrolling={false}
              disabled={disabled}
              leftArrowButtonProps={{
                classes: {
                  root: classNames('fs-ignore-rage-clicks', 'ck-previousmonth'),
                },
              }}
              rightArrowButtonProps={{
                classes: {
                  root: classNames('fs-ignore-rage-clicks', 'ck-nextmonth'),
                },
              }}
            />
```

I understand that I should be passing whatever class I'm trying to make somewhere onto Dialogprops, but I'm unable to find anything in the documentation that mentions what other props/attributes I can use besides my use of Paper props, which has allowed me to get classes on the entire dialogue box instead of the individual dates.
Dialog box:
[image: Dialogbox]

Comment: 1. Are you using MUI v5? 2. Why do you want to get the classes? Do you want to style a specific day?

Comment: @NearHuscarl I'm using Material UI v4.11.4 however I'm using Material UI/pickers v3.2.1. I'm both trying to style the day and build Auto Tests with cypress